# прошу помочь с файлом .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Я создал файл  .htaccess и впихнул туда следующий код:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f  #запрет на вывод файлов
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d  #запрет на вывод папок
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

и после добавления этого файла в корень проекта моя индексная страница перестала открываться Error 500. Помогите понять в чем дело пожалуйста.

Делаю все на Openserver.

В адресной строке всегда идет перенаправление по адресу http://php/Testmvc /
Повторюсь что без файла .htaccess все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения за этот глупый вопрос, но мало ли найдется такой как я.
Для начала нужно посмотреть логи OpenServer, путь /userdate/logs
В моем случае была ошибка RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
Что означает что я вставил никому не нужные пробелы в RewriteCond после восклицательного знака.